# File is missing from ipa and apk packages

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. I included an appsettings.json file in the shared project. It is an "embedded resource" and "copy if newer". When I run a Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps, the generated api (for iOS) and apk (for Android) packages do not have appsettings.json. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: an embedded resource is not a file.  It is, as the name implies, embedded in the assembly

Comment: How do you know that is not included? It should be inside the .dll, not as a file

Comment: @Jason, Thank you, got it now.